# Delete rows based on intermediate dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
df = 

freq     id
  11      a
  11      b
  10      c
  9       d
  1       e
  1       f
```

I want to see how many times every value of `freq` is stored and if recorded one time, remove it.
Desired output:

```
  count = 

freq     recordings
  11      2
  10      1
   9      1
   1      2
```

and then

```
df = 

freq     id
  11      a
  11      b
   1      e 
   1      f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per your logic, you sould not have `10` as `freq` in your output since it appears only once:

```
df[df.groupby('freq')['freq'].transform('count').ne(1)] #change to .gt() for greater than 1
```

---

```
    freq id
0    11  a
1    11  b
4     1  e
5     1  f
```

Comment: Working. But an additional question. Is it possible to put a range? For example. Not only when it is 1 but Less than 10?

Comment: @Mamed range meaning greater than 0 and less than 10?

Comment: If 10, then neglect it - this meaning

Comment: @Mamed sorry didnt get it, can you explain again? so if greater than 1 keep it but if 10 dont keep it? can you try `df.groupby('freq')['freq'].filter(lambda x: (x.count()>1)&(x.count()<10))` or similarly `df[df.groupby('freq')['freq'].transform(lambda x: (x.count()>1)&(x.count()<10))]` ?

Answer (score 2):

IIUC `duplicated`

```
df=df[df.freq.duplicated(keep=False)].copy() # add copy for prevent the future copy warning 
   freq id
0    11  a
1    11  b
4     1  e
5     1  f
```